# read from a text file in tar.bz2 without extracting it

Tags: unix, tar

I want to read a file in tar.bz2 file without extracting it, just like unzip -p.

suppose I have a file named abc.bz2, inside this file, there are 4 files, a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt.

I just want to read from b.txt without extracting it.

i have tried it using the below command

```
tar -xvjf abc.tar.bz2 b.txt
```

it is not working. can anyone please help?

Comment: It works here just fine.

Comment: @JamesBrown did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it did. How did it not work for you?

Comment: don't know why its not working, but trying the same, and its not giving the file output. its only listing the file.

Comment: might be that was because of low corrupted file!